# evaluate the triple integral $z/( x^2 + z^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

i set this up in the order $dxdzdy$ and i tried factoring out the z, but I'm not sure how to integrate the denominator. I tried raising it to the -1 power and putting it to the top, and using u substitution, but there is no extra x. Can someone show me detailed steps on how to do this triple integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your innermost integral is with respect to $x$, and after factoring our the $z$ from the numerator, you need to integrate $\displaystyle\int_0^z\frac{1}{x^2+z^2}\,dx$ (for this innermost integral). Hint: there are two useful antiderivative rules for functions like this:
$$\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx=\arctan(x)+C \quad \text{and} \quad \int\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{a}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C,$$
where in the second one we assume $a>0$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{aligned}\int_1^4\int_1^z\int_0^z \frac{z}{x^2+z^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz &= \int_1^4\int_1^z \left[\arctan(x/z)\right]_0^z \,dy\,dz\\\
&=\int_1^4\int_1^z \frac{\pi}{4}\,dy\,dz\\
&=\int_1^4 \frac{\pi}{4}(z-1)\,dz\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\left[\frac{z^2}{2}-z\right]_1^4\\
&=\frac{9\pi}{8}
\end{aligned}$$